# Spring Boot: Autowired mapper fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am new to spring boot and mybatis. I create a repo which has structure:

```
main
    java
        com
           ssm
              controller
                  UserController.java
              mapper
                  UserMapper.java # can generated by mybatis generator
              dao
                  UserDao.java # which extends interface UserMapper
              model
                  User.java
              service
                  UserService.java
                  UserServiceImpl.java
              UserSpringBootApplication.java
                   
    resources
        com
           ssm
              xml
                 UserMapper.xml
                 UserDao.xml
        static
        templates
        application.properties
        mybatis-config.xml
```

In file `UserSpringBootApplication.java`, its content is

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In file `UserDao.java`:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserDao extends UserMapper {


   // example
   @ResultMap("Record")
   @Select("select * from UserTable")
   List<User> getAllRecords();
}
```

In file `UserMapper.java`:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper
```

In file `application.properties`:

```
# database config
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxx

# mybatis
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

In file `UserServiceImpl.java`, I try to autowire UserDao. But when running application,
it gives me error: `Field UserDao in com.ssm.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.ssm.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.`

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
     
    // ...
}
```

- How can I handle this case?
- Any wrong with setting in `application.properties`?
- Is structure of my repo is reasonable?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share your code snipped for UserDao? what does it do?

Comment: @vaibhavsahu I add some example in `UserDao`.  Since I generate `UserMapper.java` by mybatis-generator, I try to add new sql function by `UserDao` which extends `UserMapper`.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This is only a solution for `MapStruct`, the real solution is in the comments!

You should user the `@Mapper` annotation like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
```

From the javadoc:

> spring: the generated mapper is a Spring bean and can be retrieved via @Autowired

See: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'componentModel'`. It seems there is no parameter `componentModel` for `Mapper`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was confused with MapStruct.

Comment: Did you add mybatis-spring-boot-starter as a dependency?

Comment: sorry, I didn't add mybatis-spring-boot-starter as a dependency. It works now!!! Thanks a lot!!! Why I need this dependency?

Comment: You could add @MapperScan("your.base.package") to your Spring configuration class.
But normally the mybatis-spring-boot-starter should do that for you.

Can you add the maven/gradle dependency config for spring boot / mybatis to your question?

Comment: That dependency bundles mybatis and adds some Spring magic ;-)
For example the component scanning for @Mapper annotation